# Java-Programs sharing class.. sometimes! Why?

Tags: java, rmi

I am running into the following, to me, deeply confusing, problem regarding the behaviour of Java when it comes to shared classes.
Setup I am working with:
One .jar-library to handle the logging.
One Client-Jar, which has a dependency on the logging-jar.
One Server-Jar, which had a dependency on both client and logging.

Server and Client communicate via RMI.
The logging-jar contains only one class, which holds a static "java.util.logging.Logger"-object.

Now, SOMETIMES only, when the client launches, it apparently accesses the logging-object the Server uses! Strangely, this does not ALWAYS happen. For example, on my IDE, it does NOT happen when I launch client and server in debugging-mode, but it DOES happen when the server runs on debug, and the client runs normally. The issue seems connected to using RMI somehow.

I am at a total loss as to why this would happen, and above all, why having debug on or not makes such a difference.

Reason I know the access the same class: the moment the client does access it, the default-logfile changes. So, basically, the server was previously doing it's regular logging in "server.log", and suddenly there is a "client.log"-file, which is then used for standard logging by the server.

Comment: How do you know it is accessing the server's object?

Comment: Hmm... good point, I will describe the symptom I see ^^

Comment: You are not running both client and server in the same JVM process, right?

Comment: It sounds like its running in the same process. In the logging jar, do you statically set the file  towhich is logged?

Comment: About the same process: they should be different ones, unless my IDE does VERY strange things indeed. Also, apparently the issues also appears when Server and Client are running in separate machines! But yes, the default logger is static.

Comment: Well you say your server code makes use of some client code. Presumably that gets loaded when the first connection is made and messes with the logger (because it contains code that should not be running when used from the server, but things like static initializer blocks will fire).

Comment: @Thilo: I have tried to hunt down the issues based on that... but what confuses me most is the unreliability of it happening! *goes testing another scenario to see if it still happens...*

Comment: If Server and Client are running on different machines, they cannot *(physically impossible)* use the same logger instance.